# start process, then attach to tmux pane when needed

Tags: command-line, services, tmux

So, I'm trying to set up a tmux window that gives me a at-a-glance overview of everything on my multi-purpouse server computer. I'd like to have one pane of that window display the console output of the minecraft server that I run. The problem is that the minecraft server is started on boot via a script, but the tmux status window should be able to be started whenever. So, I need to find a way to start a process detached, then attach it to a pane in tmux (and be able to detach it again later)

Thus far, I have tried:

- `nohup Server.sh &` can detach server, runs in backround, but can't find the job while inside tmux.
- running `Server.sh` inside a screen session, then attaching to the screen session inside of tmux. Works, but the inner screen session prevents me from providing input to the outer tmux session until I detach or exit again.
- `tail -f` 'ing a file that has a copy of the console output. Works well for output,  but doesn't take input. Plus is inelegant, and there are efficency concerns with the constant polling.